# RPI - Remote debug node js with Atom

Tags: node.js, atom-editor

I'm trying to debug a Node.js running on RPI.

The following video shows how do to it with webstorm https://vimeo.com/175284169

but when I do the same procedure with Atom, when I debug it display the source code of the main file from the actual RPI path therefore I cannot set break points.

How do I map the local source to the remote source in Atom so that I can set breakpoints?